# Exporting academic references from Word 2007 to Mendeley

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-word, data-transfer

I came to know about mendeley just now and initially i was using MS word 2007 for reference writing.  How to import the references from MS word 2007 to mendeley?

Answer (score 1):

Your best approach is to do this manually. Even if you do try to automate the process, you will have to edit each one anyway, and it will be very time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend finding some software to transform the Microsoft Word references file (stored in C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Bibliography\Sources.xml) to a format such as BibTex, RIS, Endnote XML or Zotero library, which are the formats supported by Mendeley when you choose Add File.